# Magento CODNITIVE sidenav move to other div

Tags: php, html, css, magento

We are making a new page in magento but with a little bit customized design.
What we want is to make the CODNITIVE extension side navigator (Categories) to move into another div. 
Example:
[image: Example]

I've tried several codes to fix this but it's quite a challange to do it all in CMS pages,
While I need to call out the phtml of the CODNITIVE side navigator. 
I've looked at some forums too but none of them are related to this case...

Any suggestions? Maybe the path to the source of the CMS pages?
Or the code to put it in another div?